# TraefiK: Customer header name case is changed with Pascal Casing

Tags: traefik

We are supplying a custom header and the name of the custom header is converted as Pascal casing.

Eg> `csrftoken` is changed as `Csrftoken`.

Please clarify. why this convention is modified, why can't you use as is. Because of this case sensitive operation, the respected header values are not read.

```
<Label Key="traefik.frontend.headers.customRequestHeaders"> csrftoken </Label>
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [RFC2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-4.2)

> Field names are case-insensitive.

More about how it works in Go: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/5022